# No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, afnetworking

Hi I have a problem with new Xcode and AFNetworking.
On xcode5 I don't have that problems but I start to make some changes and updates.
Problem is:

> No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector
>   'setImageWithURL

And code part:

```
  NSString *showThumb = [[[[SettingDataClass instance] getSetting] objectForKey:@"appearance_option"] objectForKey:@"category_browse_show_thumb"];
if([showThumb isEqualToString:@"show"])
{
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
img = cell.imageView;
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[ToolClass instance] decodeHTMLCharacterEntities:[[aryDic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumb"]]]
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"image_loading_placeholder", nil)]
               completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

                   img.image = [[ToolClass instance] imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(57, 57) source:image];

               }];
```

Where could be a problem and why this code doesn't work with Xcode6?
I will be very grateful for help

Answer (score 9):

Try including `"UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"` in the file that uses the method.

Comment: I am facing same issue on react-native any help?

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` does not work like that. You will need to add `AFNetworking`'s `UIImageView` category to get the `setImageWithURL` method.

Comment: can you elaborate it please ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [apples documentation about `UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html). As You can see there is no method like `setImageWithURL`.

[AFNetworking has subclass of UIImageView](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html). It has a method named `setImageWithURL`. If you want to use this method you need to import that class. Hope this helps.. :)

You should be writing this:

```
img = cell.imageView;
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[ToolClass instance] decodeHTMLCharacterEntities:[[aryDic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumb"]]]
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"image_loading_placeholder", nil)]
               completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

                   img.image = [[ToolClass instance] imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(57, 57) source:image];

               }];
```

And your cell should have a `UIImageView+AFNetworking` type of imageView.

Comment: `UIImageView+AFNetworking *img`? That's not how categories work.